# Bash script with wget argument list too long

Tags: bash, wget

I'm trying to download the newest files added to a website every week. The problem with that is the files url have a some kind of not very complex hash, to be precise a number between 10^5 and 10^6. I've written a simple bash script that tries all the combinations. That's why probably I'm getting the error argument list is too long. But 99% of the links are not valid so maybe there is a way to bypass this. 
This is how my script looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `seq 1 10`;
do
    fileno="0$i"
    wget --continue --timestamping --directory-prefix=photos/ http://sampleurl.com/file$fileno.{99999..1000000}.jpeg
done
for i in `seq 10 25`;
do
    wget --continue --timestamping --directory-prefix=photos/ http://sampleurl.com/file$i.{99999..1000000}.jpeg
done
```

Comment: Wow. Smart sites are going to throttle or block your connections as a very, very bad spider.

Comment: Use *lftp*, or search in DOM for files.

Comment: Also, be aware that you can ask a server for last-modified times using wget if you want to be _less_ annoying.

Comment: How do I do that exactly with wget and/or lftp?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for` loop:

```
for i in {99999..1000000}; do
    wget ...
done
```

Of course you can optimize it by wget'ing multiple files without exceeding the command line length limits.